# WSO2 Http Endpoint Error Handling

Tags: http, wso2, endpoint, wso2-esb

I'm currently trying to implement error handling on a http endpoint.
This endpoint is used to POST data via a rest API.

```
<endpoint name="Test_Post_Endpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <http method="post" statistics="enable" uri-template="https://{uri.var.host}/api/{uri.var.api}">
    <timeout>
        <duration>60000</duration>
        <responseAction>discard</responseAction>
    </timeout>
    <markForSuspension>
        <errorCodes>500</errorCodes>
        <retriesBeforeSuspension>5</retriesBeforeSuspension>
        <retryDelay>60000</retryDelay>
    </markForSuspension>
  </http>
  <description>Test API</description>
</endpoint>
```

My goal is to let the ESB retry to connect to the endpoint every minutes maximum 5 times in case of http error 500 (in the ideal world event if the host is not reachable, in case of network issue...)
It this the correct approach ?

Thanks for helping

Nicolas

Comment: Well for the errors it seems I need to use the predefined error codes from WSO2 (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Error+Handling). What I'm not really sure about is (according to the doc) : If the HTTP PassThrough transport is used, and a connection level error occurs, the error code is calculated using the following equation:
Error code = Base error code + Protocol State. But I have no clue how to compute this.